# Android newest system version could not read .cer file public key

Tags: java, android, public-key-exchange

I want get public key from `.cer` file, but failure.
I find this error from Android newest system version, i can get public key in my lower Android system version.

```
String path = "/Users/mycompute/Projects/Test/src/workspace/mykeychain.cer";
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
Certificate c = cf.generateCertificate(in);
PublicKey pubkey = c.getPublicKey();

in.close();
```

this code `Certificate c = cf.generateCertificate(in);` make error

error message:

```
java.io.IOException: Unknown named curve: 1.2.156.10197.1.301
```

what should i do?

i want get the file Hex public key.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63171510/java-security-cert-certificateparsingexception-java-io-ioexception-unknown-nam help?